# How do you send Serial text to arduino through java

Tags: java, serial-port

Hello I have an Arduino UNO connected to its LCD display. I programmed it to display any text you want by sending serial text to it. I have been Google Searching ways to do this but I haven't seemed to find a way for sending serial in java.

I am looking for an API or someway to possibly send serial text to my Arduino via USB. I chose java because I am more familiar with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [RXTX Java library](http://rxtx.qbang.org/wiki/index.php/Main_Page), it's a java serial communication library and works great with Arduino. Also the official Arduino website provides an example for Java-Arduino communication with help of this library, see [here](https://playground.arduino.cc/Interfacing/Java).